# How to pass a cmdlet as parameter value in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, system.management

How can I pass a cmdlet as a parameter value in C#? In other words, what would the the .NET equivalent of the following be?

```
PS> Get-Content -Path (Some-Cmdlet)
```

I have the following code:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create(session);
ps.AddComand("Get-Content").AddParameter("Path", "(Some-Cmdlet)");
```

However, the string "(Some-Cmdlet)" gets passed verbatim. It is not interpreted. I have also tried:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create(session);
var cmd = new Command("Some-Cmdlet");
ps.AddComand("Get-Content").AddParameter("Path", cmd);
```

Unfortunately, it gives the same result. It seems to be calling `ToString()` on the `Command` object, rather than evaluating it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no way to have a parameter value evaluated. From what I can discover, you need to use `AddScript` instead of `AddCommand`. It's also necessary to alter the expression, from what you would write on the commandline, if you want to have parameters.

In my case, I used the form:

```
var flag = "xyz";
ps.AddScript(@"param([string]$Flag) Get-Content -Path (Some-Cmdlet -Flag $Flag)")
    .AddParameter("Flag", flag);
```

There may be a better way, but this works.